Use Google API's to push google forms responses to google my business reviews
I have been trying to use Zapier as well as Google's APIs any way I know how to allow customers to fill out a form with a rating and a short answer, and offering them the option to push it to google. However, I can't figure out how to accomplish that. I've tried writing it, but I am getting hung up understanding where to find web hooks, and how they are created. As well as what URLs Zapier's API beta uses.
Right now, I am just using Zapier since I don't fully understand how to create webhooks. I have tried synching the short answer with the review, and the number rating with the star rating. I've included images of the build that I'm using. The first and last step are the only essential ones. And I have included the error that I am getting.
enter image description hereenter image description hereenter image description here
I know there is also a way to do this through Google's GMB API's. Has anyone found a path to create forms that push your reviews to google?
